# jQuery deferred:

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I have a function. The inside of the function looks like:

```
if (isNewCustomer) {
    doSomething();
    cleanup();
}
else {
    $.getJSON(..., function(result) {
        doSomethingElse();
        cleanup();
    });
}
```

I was hoping I could simply this by using deferred. My attempt looks like:

```
var do_it = doSomething;

if (!isNewCustomer) {
    do_it = $.getJSON(..., function(result) {
        doSomethingElse();
    });
}

$.when(do_it).done(function() {
    cleanup();
});
```

But this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Renaming variable `do` to `do_it`. This isn't the problem with the code. The problem is that when `do_it` is `doSomething`, `doSomething` doesn't get executed.

Comment: *do* is a keyword in javascript

Answer (score 3):

do is a keyword in javascript, so better rename the variable.

```
var do_it = doSomething;

if (!isNewCustomer) {
    do_it = $.getJSON(..., function(result) {
        doSomethingElse();
    });
}
//          || << note me
$.when(do_it()).done(function() {
    cleanup();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but when `do_it` is `doSomething`, `doSomething` is never invoked.

Comment: I'm don't know jquery deferred at all, but it seem that you have to actually *call* the condition function inside the *when* call.
I've edited my answer.

Comment: 1. In your original q, you don't execute the function. you just pass in function as a argument.( no parenthesis).    2) Considering thats a easy one to spot, if your doSomething returns a new Deferred, then this won't work either in the sense that cleanUp will be called only after this returned deferred gets resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result;

if (isNewCustomer) {
    result = doSomething();
} else {
    result = $.getJSON( ..., function( data ) {
        doSomethingElse( data );
    });
}

$.when( result ).done(function() {
    cleanup();
});
```

See the code above: you never called the function just like Gigi pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/timlint/tg7xqtha/

Using Deferred is the way to go. It's a little hard to grasp the flow sometimes and how to pass data around but this example may give you some insight.

You can almost think of a deferred as a flag. in a function you create a deferred object.

the function returns the .promise() for that deferred. this allows you to call the function doSomething(bool).done() and do something once it finishes. You resolve the deferred when you know the task is complete and it won't be called until then.

```
function doSomething(isNewCustomer)
{

// think of a deferred as a flag object in a way
var d = $.Deferred();


if(!isNewCustomer)
{
    $.getJSON(..., function(result) {
        // work with data
    }).done(function() {
        // finisn up data

        // set deferred to resolved
        d.resolve();
    });
}
else
{
    // some business logic

    // set deferred to resolved
    d.resolve();   
}
// returning the promise lets you call .done()
// on this function call in the main call
return d.promise();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need an explicit Deferred. If you pass when() an argument that is not a Deferred, the function is invoked immediately, and is probably why you're getting unexpected results.

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

if (isNewCustomer) {
    deferred.resolveWith(doSomething());
}
else {
    $.getJSON(...).
        done(function(result) {
            deferred.resolveWith(doSomethingElse(result));
        }).
        fail(function(...) {
            deferred.rejectWith(...);
        });
}

deferred.promise().always(function() { cleanup(); });
```

Comment: Using a Deferred won't change a thing... $.when does this internally already... and I know it because I actually coded it.

Comment: Are you aware that you added a snarky reply to every answer in here, including your own?  Are you also aware that you're not winning points for the jQuery team here?